# postfix sending only short messages ( emails ) but not long messages?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, spam

when I am sending a short email from "xx@domain.com" or any other email acc , the message is received well in the inbox of Gmail , hotmail etc , but if I send the message again with long text the email is bouncing back with Error :

```
<xx@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[xx.xx.153.27] said:
550-5.7.1 [xx.xx.xx.167 12] Gmail has detected that this message is
550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to
Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError for more 550
5.7.1 information. gz13-20020a170906f2cd00b00a0e79089b8fsi528438ejb.874 -
gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

PS : SPF AND DMARC is set well and message score test is 10/10  by mail-tester.com

**example of received message :**

```
title: hi
body : hi
```

**example of not received message :**

```
title : hi
body : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pellentesque auctor consectetur. Phasellus quis ipsum consequat, ultrices est eget, mollis magna. Maecenas porttitor enim vel laoreet vestibulum. Phasellus tincidunt mi in erat efficitur, a maximus est vestibulum. Etiam faucibus purus quis euismod accumsan. Vestibulum placerat mollis erat vitae elementum. Sed id lacinia augue. Sed venenatis, tellus in elementum mollis, eros diam maximus arcu, eu bibendum risus justo ac nunc. Phasellus suscipit ex et augue ultricies, mollis tincidunt est consequat. Morbi id sollicitudin purus, sed consequat orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Sed tincidunt nunc et pretium fringilla. Suspendisse sollicitudin, lectus nec fringilla iaculis, metus turpis maximus massa, vitae elementum tellus nisl eleifend massa. Morbi finibus, velit nec eleifend maximus, nisl nunc elementum diam, hendrerit porttitor nisl ipsum at purus. Integer convallis rhoncus dolor ac condimentum. Sed suscipit vitae tellus eget gravida.
```

I am sending emails from Usermin panel by ( Vertiualmin ).

why my server is not sending out a long messages ?

Comment: Did you try the tools mentioned in the help article linked in that error message?

Comment: Don't do the Lorem ipsum that's configured in many spam filters. But try do actual message with some substance

Comment: How are you sending your e-mails ? Are you using a normal email client? Or do you send email from a script/code? In either case: the support link gives some reasons, implied there is that even though all SPF, DMARC and friends are correct, spammy contents and bad IP-address reputation will still result in mail being rejected. (Because spammers can set up SPF and DMARC too.)

Comment: @HBruijn but why only messages with small text length are received ? its only rejecting any email with long text .

Comment: @Turdie I did changed to real text one text still same issue , only accepting emails with small message length

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yep I did . my email score test is 10/10

Comment: Please check using this link https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en#zippy=%2Crequirements-for-all-senders

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en#zippy=%2Crequirements-for-all-senders

In summary Gmail requires

- SPF, DKIM and DMARC Your sending IP address must have a PTR record.
- Format messages according to the Internet Format Standard (RFC 5322).
- If your messages are in HTML, format them according to HTML standards
- Use a TLS connection for transmitting email.